# Are the components of the curvature tensor defined by the Robertson-Walker metric constant?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, curvature

In the Robertson-Walker solution the curvature is uniform. However the space is "expanding" and so the matter density is decreasing over time (or not because it's modelled as a perfect fluid?). Does the expansion affect the components of the curvature tensor if this is the case?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker_metric#Curvature) has the Ricci curvature tensor.

Comment: I saw that and wondered if changing Ricci tensor components imply changing Riemann tensor components. My intuition for them isn't great yet but I assume that implies the Riemann curvature also changes since it's just a contraction of it?

Comment: Actually I now see the components are a function of the changing metric, thank you.

Comment: It has a warped metric from the direct product of two Riemann manifolds, namely, $M \times_{f} S$, where $\tilde{M}$ is an open interval $\mathbb{R}$ with the metric $\tilde g=-dt^{2}$,$(S,\hat g)$ is a $3$ dimensional Euclidean space of constant curvature, and $f$ is the warp function $a(t)$. The space-time metric is $g=\tilde g+\hat g=-dt^{2}+a(t)^{2}\hat g$. Typically, the calculation of the Ricci tensor is done using a tetrad frame field and Cartan' calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to put the metric in the form

$$ ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t)\left[d\chi^2 + f^2(\chi) d\Omega^2 \right]$$

or alternatively

$$ ds^2 = a^2(\tau)\left[d\tau^2 - d\chi^2 - f^2(\chi) d\Omega^2 \right],$$

where

$$ f(\chi) = \sin\chi,\,\, \chi,\,\, \sinh\chi $$

for positive, zero and negative curvature, respectively. *f* is the radial coordinate commonly denoted by *r* in Robertson-Walker coordinates. This makes it explicit that coefficients of the metric change in time, and likewise the space curvature changes in time because the metric describes uniform *space* curvature - not uniform spacetime  curvature.

You can see that coefficients of the curvature tensor change in time directly from Einstein's equation. As you say, the energy/matter density is decreasing, so Einstein's equation is a statement that curvature is decreasing.

diagrams for the above coordinates are shown at [Description of singularities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/534965/description-of-singularities/535023#535023)

Comment: Why can you write $a^2(\tau)$ multiplying the $d\tau^2$ term? Doesn't that imply the entire metric is changing and not just the spacial part?

Comment: Coordinates are arbitrary. This is just a change to a non-uniform scale on the time axis, but it has the effect of meaning that the radial speed of light is constant, which can be convenient. In these coordinates the "expansion of the universe" is replaced with "the contraction of matter", but it is just a different way of looking at the same thing. Just as you can map the surface of the Earth in many different ways.

Comment: Solved, thanks for taking the time to answer.